# Web Scraping - converter tabela HTML em dict python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scraping

Estou tentando transformar uma tabela HTML em dict@python, me deparei com alguns problemas e solicito a ajuda de vocês.

Segue até onde consegui chegar...

```
def impl12(url='http://www.geonames.org/countries/', tmout=2):
    import requests
    from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
    import csv

    page = requests.get(url=url, timeout=tmout)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    #print('\nsoup >>>', soup)
    data = soup.find_all(id="countries")[0].get_text(separator='; ')

    #print('\ndata >>>', data, type(data))
    data = data.split('; ')

    content = csv.DictReader(data)
    for linha in content:
        pass
        print(linha)
```

Comment: O que está retornando até agora do seu script?

Comment: um dicionario com cada elemento , https://pastebin.com/WjiebRLZ

Comment: Você que que o que seja a chave e o que seja o valor? Porque as linhas possuem vários dados..

Ou quer que as chaves seja a sigla e os valores um outro dicionário com os outros dados da linha?

{"BR":{"Country":"Brazil","Capital":"Brasilia",,,}}

Comment: Isto. Com o  csv.DictReader, o titulo do campo vira chave, e cada linha vira um dicionário.

Comment: Entendi.. vou verificar aqui..

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63170/discussion-between-marlysson-and-britodfbr).

Answer (score 4):

O beautifullsoup está sendo usado de forma redundante aí - você só acha o início da tabela, e aí usa "força bruta" para separar todos os elementos por "; ", e depois trata o resultado como texto puro. Dessa forma vocẽ não preserva a estrutura de tabela, e fica difícil saber o que é cabeçalho da tabela e o que é conteúdo.

Nada vai criar "por mágica" os cabeçalhos para você. O módulo CSV tem ferramentas para extrair dicionários a partir de um  arquivo de texto estruturado em disco. Mesmo que a chamada ao `get_text("; ")` transformasse seus dados num arquivo CSV bem estruturado - o que não acontece por que as quebras de linha necessárias para um arquivo CSV não vão estar lá (Exceto por coincidência da formatação do HTML), você teria que passar um iterador que entregasse uma linha dessas de cada vez para o DictReader - mas ao fazer o split em  "; ", o seu iterador passa uma célula por vêz. Dai ele te retorna um dicionário com o conteúdo de cada célula, sem saber o que é cabeçalho ou não.

Para fazer esse tipo de coisa nãoo existe uma fŕomula pronta-  cada página é uma página, e "olhar pro HTML" e criar a estrutura de parsing que vai funcionar de primeira, é bem difícil. O melhor é fazer no modo interativo do Python - você recupera os daods da página com o requests.get, cria o objeto `soup` e aí experimenta com os vários métodos desse objeto soup e a estrutura da página até achar como quer deixar seus dados

Nesse caso, você veria que aṕós achar a tabela "children", iterar sobre a mesma com um "for" vai retornar alternadamente uma linha da tabela (incluindo o cabeçalho) e uma string de texto - que é o whitespace.

Talvez seja possível fazer algo assim então:

```
def importa(url='http://www.geonames.org/countries/', tmout=2):
    import requests
    from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
    from collections import OrderedDict

    page = requests.get(url=url, timeout=tmout)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    #print('\nsoup >>>', soup)
    table = soup.find_all(id="countries")[0]

    result = []

    headers = None
    for row in table:
        # Pule as linhas que não contém tags html
        if isinstance(row, str):
            continue
        # Assume que a primeira linha com conteúdo são os cabeçalhos
        if not headers:
            # cria uma lista com o conteúdo de texto de cada tag na linha:
            headers = [cell.get_text() for cell in row]
            continue

        row_contents = [cell.get_text() for cell in row]
        data_dict = OrderedDict(pair for pair in zip(headers, row_contents))
        result.append(data_dict)

    return result


from pprint import pprint
pprint(importa())
```

(Aqui funciona - note o uso do `OrderedDict` para facilitar a visualização dos dicionários)

Comment: Demorei bastante para entender o código.

Finalmente intendi. Valeu pela ajuda!